# I want to autofill gmail signup page by parsing data I receive through a web form

Tags: javascript, php, webforms, gmail, autofill

I work for a NGO and we are on a mission to teach rural people on how to operate emails. A part of my job is to create gmail accounts of the registered people and hand them off to the people after the event. My field team collects the data i need to create an account on hard copies. So i need to record the data in a database online via a web form. The web form I use is exactly similar to the one that gmail uses. So currently i am entering data twice on my database as well as on gmail. Is there anyway i can push the data i enter on my web form to the signup page on gmail and from there just fill in the captcha and create an account?

Please advise!

Comment: i dont have code access but its a simple php form that collects the data and stores it in a MySQL database.. What i want is when i fill all the data and hit submit, it should do 2 things.. 1> Store it in the database and 2> take all the information and autofil/populate on https://accounts.google.com/signup so that all i have to do is fill in captcha and create an account.

Answer (score 0):

Try [scrapy login form](https://github.com/scrapy/loginform). Not sure will work.

Comment: Thanks, thats good for login forms.. not sure about registration forms